# Siteorigin post loop widget

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, siteorigin

I'm using the Siteorigin page builder's Post Loop Widget to display posts on a page. There are more than one post blocks in the page so I need no duplicated posts. There's an offset solutionm but I can't figure out, how to implement it: the widget has an input field with the label 'Additional query arguments. See query_posts.' where I can write query parameters. "offset" => 2, and offset=2 parameters doesn't work. Does anybody can figure it out, how it works? Thank you!

[image: The input field:]

Query posts link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sticky Posts

If you have any sticky posts present the Post Loop widget won't work 100% as expected - it'll count the sticky posts as offset but still output them so it'll appear as though nothing changed.

Try setting Sticky posts to Ignore sticky and then add offset=2 to the Additional field.

Comment: You are right Misplon. Ignored sticky posts and it's working well. Thank you!